# Is there a difference in pronunciation for un, a, à, as and et, es and est?

Tags: prononciation, voyelles

I'm listening to the storyteller while I'm reading my book in French. I cannot hear any difference between *un*, *a*, *à* and *as* But is there a difference in pronunciation?

I have the same question for *et*, *es* and *est*. 
The only difference I have heard is that *et* is pronounced as the "e" in *English* and *est* is pronounced as "a" like in *cat* in English. And also "et" is not affected by liaison. Example:

- *Et un* (“and a”) will be pronunced as "e aa". Forget about the T.
- But *est un* (“is a”) will be pronunced as "et aa".

Are these pronunciations correct? 
Please, don't use weird letters while you are trying to describe how it should be pronounced. I don't understand them.

Comment: When I have a cold and a stuffy nose, I believe I pronounce *a* and *un* an undistinguishable way. Moreover, when I was a kid, I used to pronounce *un* as [ỹŋ]... Sorry about the weird letters, but how do you want to represent pronunciation in written material without using standardized symbols?

Comment: About the "weird letters": I understand the need for a standarised system of transcribing sounds into printed work. However, you are essentially saying that we cannot discuss pronunciation _unless_ we invest in the effort of learning the system. That seems a bit unfortunate; we can discuss quantum mechanics without learning the advanced maths that is used formally to describe it.

Comment: If you're not familiar with French vowels, I suggest you read [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_phonology#Vowels) as a start. It has "weird letters" but there's an example word for each sound that you can play so you can hear exactly how it sounds.

Comment: @OscarBravo IPA (the "weird letters") is useful because they represent sounds that don't exist in English, as well as sounds that _do_ exist in English. Otherwise you're left saying "it's halfway between 'a' and 'e', but with the lips rounded". Can you tell me what that sounds like without hearing it first? Also in English letters have different sounds in different words, and in different accents. You can look up IPA, even with audio clips of the sounds! Without IPA we can only discuss the sounds we've heard before, which for most of us is only the sounds in our native languages.

Comment: @CJDennis I understand the power of IPA - but if OP clearly states they're not comfortable with it, why use it as a first resort? It's like people asking questions about time dilation that have clearly no maths interest and some guys come back with answers that include tensor algebra in the Kerr metric.

Comment: @OscarBravo The problem IPA solves is how to unambiguously represent spoken sounds as written symbols. Until you have a common framework you can't meaningfully discuss anything.

Comment: @OscarBravo *I want to discuss about numbers, but don't bother me with these pesky digits...*

Comment: @jlliagre Ha! Good one :-).. But it's more like: _"I want to discuss physical phenomena but I don't understand advanced tensor algebra"_. That's still possible; though challenging for the respondent.

Comment: @OscarBravo I don't think so. To understand advanced tensor algebra, a reasonable background in mathematics is a prerequisite. To understand IPA, you just need to be able to hear, read and and memorize a few Greek like letters and diacritics. My kids were taught the IPA in primary school (CM1 or CM2, i.e. fourth/fifth grade) at a time when the math curriculum was more about simple fractions, decimal numbers, basic geometrical figures.

Comment: The main difference between *un* and *a* is that *un* is nasalized. (Depending on the exact vowels a French speaker uses, there may or may not be further differences, but that's the important one.)

Comment: You really should provide specific examples. That said, of course, *a* and *à* are pronounced the same way (all other things being equal). They are different grammatically.

Answer (score 14):

Note: It is difficult to avoid using IPA to describe pronunciation. English vowels are absolutely not equivalent to French ones, so comparisons in dictionaries (e.g. "like the *a* in *angel*") are often misleading.

Your given pronunciations are not correct:

- There is absolutely a difference between the pronunciation of *un* and that of *a*, *à*, and *as*.

  - *Un* is pronounced as /œ̃/ or possibly as /ɛ̃/. /œ̃/ is a nasalized version of the vowel in *-eur* or *-euse* suffixes (or extremely roughly, like that in the English *turn*). /ɛ̃/ is a nasalized version of the vowel in the *-enne* suffix (or like the English *bed*).
  - *A*, *à*, and *as* are pronounced as /a/, like the vowel in *chat* (or in English, the vowel in *father*). Additionally, there may [theoretically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_(French)#Optional_liaison) be a liaison for *as* when it is followed by a vowel, although this is rare in practice.

> The only difference I have heard is that *et* is pronounced as the "e" in *English* and *est* is pronounced as "a" like in *cat* in English. And also "et" is not affected by liaison.

- Your comparison here is incorrect. The options we have for pronouncing these words are /ɛ/ and /e/. These vowels are similar to that in the English *bed* and the *beginning* of the vowel diphthong in the English *pain*. The vowels that you have referred to, those in *English* and *cat*, are [/ɪ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-close_front_unrounded_vowel#Occurrence) and [/æ/](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_pr%C3%A9-ouverte_ant%C3%A9rieure_non_arrondie), both of which do not exist in phonological descriptions of "standard" French, to the best of my knowledge.

  - The dictionary reports that *et* is pronounced with /e/, and that *es* and *est* are pronounced with /ɛ/, but these pronunciations [appear](http://www.languefrancaise.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=6601) to often be confounded.
  - *Et* [is never pronounced](https://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/liaisons_obligatoires_liaisons_interdites.htm) with a liaison. *Es* and *est* may be followed with a liaison, for example in *L'amour est enfant de bohème*.

In the case of homophones, the best means of distinguishing them is context.

Comment: "as" meaning "ace" is always /as/. "Es" as in "es lettres" is always /ɛs/.

Comment: @LPH: “As” meaning “ace,” sure (and thanks for the pointer), although the OP was clearly just interested in conjugations of être and avoir and some common words, but I don’t follow “‘es’ as in ‘es lettres’”? The only instance of “es” that I can locate is the conjugation of être.

Comment: You are right, an accent is needed for that one (ès).

Comment: @LPH I see. I hadn’t been aware of that turn of phrase (at least not out of context.) I think the -ès combination might have suggested that pronunciation though in that case, seeing that it’s not entirely unheard of for the S to not be silent there.

Comment: Never mind, I'd just forgotten there was an accent on that e, that's all.

Comment: Since a large fraction of us Americans use the same vowel for *egg* and *pain*, your examples aren't that well-chosen. (Not that you should be expected to know the minutiae of American dialectical pronunciation. You just happened to pick [one](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/egg) of a handful of words containing /ɛ/ that is often pronounced with /eɪ/.)

Comment: @PeterShor I speak American English and don’t pronounce the two the same. I’ve also been working lately with students who need assistance with English literacy, and “egg” seems to be an commonly used as an example of the short E. A drill for vowel-sound correspondences might include: “E, /ε/, egg.” But I see that other regional dialects may be different.

Comment: @Maroon: If you look at [this dictionary link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/egg), you can see that both pronunciations are given for *egg*. Certainly, egg is in some sense "supposed to be" pronounced with /ε/, and it probably is for the majority of Americans, but I think it's still a bad example.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, I see what you mean; it’s more that it struck me as odd given my own experience and work. I will change the example.

Comment: Any reason why "beginning" in the "Your comparison here" para. is in italics? i.e. in that sentence you're using italics for words in English so for a second there my brain had to work more, in a way. Anyways.

Comment: +1. As a French, I never noticed that there is no liaison with *et*. I didn't know either that *et* and *est* were supposed to be pronounced differently (but I am from Burgundy where we don't make any difference between the verb endings*ai* - passe simple - and *ais* - imparfait)

Comment: Reguarding egg, there's this phenomenon called pre-velar raising in much of American English (I think upper Midwestern and West Coast especially) that turns the vowels of bag, bang, leg, length, big and king into raised variants (/a/ > [æɪ], /ɛ/ > [e] or [eɪ], /ɪ/ > [i]. Depending on the speaker, they may not fully merge this raised /ɛ/ with the /eɪ/ diphthong, but it makes words ending like egg a really bad example to use as a reference for the /ɛ/ of other languages, you better off using let or tell.

Comment: Since /ɛ̃/ in the northern half of European French is lowered and backed to [æ̃] or [ɐ̃], its closest oral equivalent is /a/ ([æ a ä ɐ] depending on dialect), so I'm not surprising the OP is having issues distinguishing them, especially since *un* in particular can lose its nasality in casual speech

Comment: @Taladris I hadn’t been either until I was looking at analyses of closed/open E for something. But I hadn’t been systematically taught pronunciation as an FLE learner. And anyway, I have a tendency to use closed E unless it’s clearly marked otherwise (to me).

Comment: The vowel in _father_ is /ɑ:/ in most English accents, not /a/, correct? (Australian springs to mind as an exception.)

Comment: @ToivoSäwén So I’ve heard, especially with the bother-father merger. But _father_ is the typical example given by dictionaries, and it’s how I perceive my own pronunciation. Also to begin with there’s for some reason a lot of confusion between the two symbols (see for example the Wiktionary entry for “as” in French).

Comment: @Maroon There is a use of es as a sole word but it comes from latin and is an old way to say what it means. Since it's latin tho I don't know if it qualifies as an instance of "es"

Answer (score 1):

un, in, ein, ain, ym are in modern times undistinguished most of the time. It's a nasal sound without real equivalence in English.
a, à, -as, -at is the same sound, like the a of father. â is usually a bit longer.

There is a clear distinction between é, et, -er and è, ê, es, est, ai, eai, -et, although young french children tend to mix them up.

Speakers from some areas, in France and in other parts of the world, may use more distinctions, ore slighty different ones. This is the less-marked parisian-area pronunciation, that has less vowels.

Note 'e' and 'eu' are yet two other different sounds alongside é and è. 'eu', 'e', 'é', 'è' will be more and more open.

Answer (score 0):

There are no vowel pronunciation differences between "a", "à" and "as". Nor between "es", "est" and "ait" though the liasons into the next word might be different due to the ending 't' or ending 's'.

There is a very significant difference between "a" and "un". The first doesn't have any nasal component to it and the sound is "clearer" for lack of a better way to express this. Depending on regional accents, "un", "ain" and "in" might sound more or less similar. I'm failing to find any English word to explain "un". Maybe you know how to pronouce "Verdun" correctly?

There is also some regional shenanigans going on with "et", "es", "est" & friends.  "et" is supposed to be a "sharp e", written 'é' whereas "es" and "est" are supposed to be "low e", written 'è'. In some regions they sound *very* similar or even indistinguishable.

Answer (score 0):

Complement

To impress upon you the importance of the implications raised by the  [remark](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/41125/17649) (note) you find in one of the answers, I join an IPA chart; it should be understood and used until it becomes known. I'll use it to answer a small part of your question.

[image]

You say "est is pronounced as "a" like in cat in English". If you look at the places of the respective vowels (ɛ, æ) of "est" and "cat" on the chart you find that they are not too far from one another and so it is normal for you at the beginning not to make them out clearly from one another. The difference is a matter of opening of the mouth: on the line segment from /a/ to /i/ the place in the mouth where the vowels are pronounced is the *front* of the mouth and all that changes along that segment is the opening of the mouth, which becomes from  most open for /a/ closest for /i/. The opening of the mouth, in the present case, is not a measure of how wide you spread your jaws in speaking but of *how high you raise your tongue in the mouth*.  So as to become familiar with the sounds you might try exercices using words with vowels with progressively lower openings or greater openings. For instance, from greatest to lowest  : Frn. "pale", Eng. "pal" Frn. "pelle" or English "pell" as in "pell-mell". By constructing sequences that way and training yourself to pronounce them you will soon become familiar with the sound and won't confuse them any more.

Corresponding to the vowels in the chart shown above, which you find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet#Vowels) you find a pronunciation chart by clicking "audio" in the line "IPA help audio full chart template" at the bottom of this chart. This will open the pronunciation chart shown below and it is only needed then to click the small triangle corresponding to the vowel you are interested in to have immediately the sound that corresponds.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I would pronounce “un” as ɑ̃ rather than œ̃.  I hear “un” pronounced as ɑ̃, sort of like a nasalized aa or nasalized ah.

Comment: *un* se prononce plutôt `[ɛ̃]`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/20791)

Comment: @Toto Ça dépend où. Moi, je le prononce [œ̃].